# Batch application won't execute

Tags: windows, batch, notepad++, batch-file, notepad

I am trying to make a Windows Troubleshooter within batch, because why not?

When I come to main menu script, the application won't execute any further, and closes. I have tried to use the CALL function to call the application main menu, and put the code in a separate program, but it won't execute then either... Does anybody know how to fix this? Code is attached below.

**First.bat**

```
@echo off 
color a 
title Windows Toubleshooter 
cd C:\windows 
cls 
echo Loading files. Please wait... {LOADING MECHANISM HERE!!} 
echo Loading complete echo Press a key to continue... 
pause >nul 
call main.bat
```

**Main.bat**

```
cls
color 7c
echo Welcome to the  Windows Troubleshooter. To continue, please chose one of the options below.


echo 1) Check for errors
echo 2) Repair errors
echo 3) Exit
echo Please chose an option: 
choice /c asdw/n /m "Chose with W A S D"
IF %errorlevel%==1 goto errorcheck
IF %errorlevel%==2 goto repair
IF %errorlevel%==3 goto exit
```

Comment: I dunno why you have the user type ASDW for the menu items labelled 1, 2, 3 - doesn't make sense to me. Anyway, where do you get stuck with all this? What does your `:errorcheck`, `:repair` and `:exit` actually look like?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: -notjustme i have not actually come so far that i have started on these. that is how i found it on the stackoverflow forum. don't remember what thread it was...

Comment: - DavidPostill do you need that too? That piece of the code works perfect.

Comment: @IsakDombestein Again, where are you getting stuck? `the application won't execute any further, and closes.` Is this before or after you get to make a choice? How does notepad and notepad++ come into the picture (the tags)?

Comment: @notjustme this is before i get to make any choices.

This is the entire code, so you can see better what i am doing wrong...

(at)echo off
color a
title Windows Toubleshooter
cd C:\windows
cls

echo Loading files. Please wait...

{LOADING MECHANISM HERE!!}

echo Loading complete
echo Press a key to continue...

pause >nul

call main.bat

and the rest is in the main post

Comment: I just ran your main.bat script and I see two issues: **1.** `ERROR: Invalid choice. The valid choice characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.` and **2.** the `%errorlevel%` is 255 and not 1, 2, or 3 so... what do you want it to do if it's not 1, 2, or 3? Open command prompt, and then type in the full path to your main.bat and then the results will stay buffered in that cmd.exe instance for you to see all this... You will obviously need to create :errorcheck and :repair routines for the GOTO to move there if that errorlevel equals that where EXIT will do that, but it's 255

Comment: So what this means with the way you have this now, once the IF statements check and the errorlevel is not 1, 2, or 3, then it does what is next (EOF) due to what you are missing or don't have logic for yet and this is why you are having a problem. Just do like I said to troubleshoot this. Open command prompt, type in full path to main.bat, and then press ENTER and see the results. Adjust CHOICE, adjust errorlevel IF statements if needed, add additional subroutines for the labels that are where it's to GOTO for 1 and 2, and add other logic what you want it to do if not EOF.